# iPhone signature capture

Tags: iphone, digital-signature, electronic-signature

Is it possible to transfer a signature from an iPhone into an .xls file via a cable (USB) connection?

Comment: A signature from an app such as autogragh. e.g. a customer signing for receipt of goods.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to capture the signature, or only the way to export it from your App to Excel via the standard accessory port/USB?

Comment: Both really as I can only find apps that transfer the signature over a network (wireless), where as I want to take the siganture and import it into an xls file on a laptop in situ.

Answer (score 7):

So, this may not be exactly what you are looking for, but this is how I capture a signature drawn by a user (with their finger/stylus).  Your UIImageView will have the drawn signature.  I have not thought about how to transfer the signature image to the .xls but you could save the image to the device's photo library then export it like you would any other image, then drop it into the .xls (I know, that's a manual process).  I hope this helps.

SignatureViewController.h

```
IBOutlet UIImageView *signatureImageView;

//Signature Drawing Items
CGPoint lastPoint;
BOOL mouseSwiped;   
int mouseMoved;
```

SignatureCaptureViewController.m

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {      
    mouseSwiped = NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    //Clear Signature on Double Tap
    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
        signatureImageView.image = nil;
        return;
    }

    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:signatureImageView];

}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    mouseSwiped = YES;

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];   

    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:signatureImageView];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(signatureImageView.frame.size);
    [signatureImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, signatureImageView.frame.size.width, signatureImageView.frame.size.height)];
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 2.0);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

    signatureImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    lastPoint = currentPoint;
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    //Clear Signature on Double Tap
    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
        signatureImageView.image = nil;
        return;
    }

    if(!mouseSwiped) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(signatureImageView.frame.size);
        [signatureImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, signatureImageView.frame.size.width, signatureImageView.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 2.0);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        signatureImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems great. I would love to see the full .h, and bit more on how to actually integrate this via interface builder though.